# Haskell, Foldr, and foldl

Tags: haskell, fold

I've been trying to wrap my head around foldr and foldl for quite some time, and I've decided the following question should settle it for me. Suppose you pass the following list [1,2,3] into the following four functions:

```
a = foldl (\xs y -> 10*xs -y) 0
b = foldl (\xs y -> y - 10 * xs) 0
c = foldr (\y xs -> y - 10 * xs) 0
d = foldr (\y xs -> 10 * xs -y) 0
```

The results will be -123, 83, 281, and -321 respectively.

Why is this the case? I know that when you pass [1,2,3,4] into a function defined as

```
f = foldl (xs x -> xs ++ [f x]) []
```

it gets expanded to ((([] ++ [1]) ++ [2]) ++ [3]) ++ [4]

In the same vein, What do the above functions a, b, c, and d get expanded to?

Comment: Did you search SO for other foldr/foldl-related questions? Many of them show expansions and have really good explanations. You might also try doing the substitutions yourself, replacing the recursive calls to fold with their definitions to get a good intuition for what's going on.

Comment: I did search SO for explanations, but I still couldn't make sense of them. None of them succeeded in showing me how to substitute foldl and foldr calls into expressions like the one above. I'm not sure how to do the substitutions myself which is why I'm asking this question. Or perhaps you mean that I look at how foldr and foldl are defined recursively, and walk through them with a, b, c, and d respectively. Sounds like a hassle where I was looking for a shortcut, but I guess if there's no other way...

Comment: I'll make sure to comment the answers when I figure it out

Comment: Have you seen http://foldl.com and http://foldr.com ?

Comment: I haven't I will check it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the two images on [Haskell Wiki's fold page](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold#List_folds_as_structural_transformations) explain it quite nicely.

Since your operations are not commutative, the results of `foldr` and `foldl` will not be the same, whereas in a commutative operation they would:

```
Prelude> foldl1 (*) [1..3]
6
Prelude> foldr1 (*) [1..3]
6
```

Using `scanl` and `scanr` to get a list including the intermediate results is a good way to see what happens:

```
Prelude> scanl1 (*) [1..3]
[1,2,6]
Prelude> scanr1 (*) [1..3]
[6,6,3]
```

So in the first case we have (((1 * 1) * 2) * 3), whereas in the second case it's (1 * (2 * (1 * 3))).

Answer (score 1):

`foldr` is a really simple function idea: get a function which combines two arguments, get a starting point, a list, and compute the result of calling the function on the list in that way.

Here's a nice little hint about how to imagine what happens during a `foldr` call:

```
foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3,4,5]
=> 1 + (2 + (3 + (4 + (5 + 0))))
```

We all know that `[1,2,3,4,5] = 1:2:3:4:5:[]`. All you need to do is replace `[]` with the starting point and `:` with whatever function we use. Of course, we can also reconstruct a list in the same way:

```
foldr (:) [] [1,2,3]
=> 1 : (2 : (3 : []))
```

We can get more of an understanding of what happens within the function if we look at the signature:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

We see that the function first gets an element from the list, then the accumulator, and returns what the next accumulator will be. With this, we can write our own `foldr` function:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f a []     = a
foldr f a (x:xs) = f x (foldr f a xs)
```

And there you are; you should have a better idea as to how `foldr` works, so you can apply that to your problems above.

Answer (score 0):

The `fold*` functions can be seen as looping over the list passed to it, starting from either the end of the list (`foldr`), or the start of the list (`foldl`). For each of the elements it finds, it passes this element and the current value of the accumulator to what you have written as a lambda function. Whatever this function returns is used as the value of the accumulator in the next iteration.

Slightly changing your notation (`acc` instead of `xs`) to show a clearer meaning, for the first left fold

```
a = foldl (\acc y -> 10*acc - y) 0              [1, 2, 3]
  = foldl (\acc y -> 10*acc - y) (0*1 - 1)      [2, 3]
  = foldl (\acc y -> 10*acc - y) -1             [2, 3]
  = foldl (\acc y -> 10*acc - y) (10*(-1) - 2)  [3]
  = foldl (\acc y -> 10*acc - y) (-12)          [3]
  = foldl (\acc y -> 10*acc - y) (10*(-12) - 3) []
  = foldl (\acc y -> 10*acc - y) (-123)         []
  = (-123)
```

And for your first right fold (note the accumulator takes a different position in the arguments to the lambda function)

```
c = foldr (\y acc -> y - 10*acc) 0              [1, 2, 3]
  = foldr (\y acc -> y - 10*acc) (3 - 10*0)     [1, 2]
  = foldr (\y acc -> y - 10*acc) 3              [1, 2]
  = foldr (\y acc -> y - 10*acc) (2 - 10*3)     [1]
  = foldr (\y acc -> y - 10*acc) (-28)          [1]
  = foldr (\y acc -> y - 10*acc) (1 - 10*(-28)) []
  = foldr (\y acc -> y - 10*acc) 281            []
  = 281
```